# Can I convert the floating part of a double into an integer (without using string conversions)?

Tags: c#, c++

Example:  If I have 7.2828, I just want to get the 2828 as an integer.

Comment: I know this is a duplicate (I answered it at some point), but you realize 7.28 and 7.0028 will both end up with an answer of 28, correct? You'll have no idea what the original floating part was.

Comment: can you clarify how you want these two numbers handled: 7.02828 and 7.000002828

Comment: How would you want the likes of 0.000000000125657542619998 dealt with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decimal is your friend...

Convert your number to a decimal and then do this.

```
       decimal d = (decimal)7.2828;
       int val = decimal.GetBits(d - decimal.Truncate(d))[0];
```

the neat thing about a decimal is that it stores the val as an int, and then just stores a decimal point position.

Answer (score 3):

If `d` is the original value, just do the following.

```
((int)(d * 10000)) % 10000
```

Comment: is not specifically for this number. if you don't know the number of digits behing the dot. 10000 doesn't work.

Comment: In C++ you should use static_cast to cast double to int. Final code should look like static_cast<int>(d*10000.0)%10000. C-cast is only for compatibility. Please, don't use it without reason.

Comment: JIa3ep, the question is tagged with c#. (Actually, for some reason I originally though the question was for Java :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

In C++, use `double modf(double, double *)`:

```
double value;
double fractional_part;
double integer_part= modf(value, &fractional_part);
int fractional_part_as_integer= fractional_part * 10000; // insert appropriate scale here.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can. Most CPUs cannot represent 7.2828 as a double (IBM mainframes being the exception). The reason is that they represent doubles as a sum of powers of 2. The "7" part is easy: 1+2+4. The fracational bit is harder: 0.25+0.0.03125+0,0009765625..... - an infinite sequence. For practical reasons, this sequence is truncated. And the resulting double will be close to 7.2828. Perhaps 7.282800000000001245. This probably won't fit into an (32 bits) integer.